# updating textview when entering data in the edittext directly

Tags: android

I know that there is many answers on this topic but I am still having a problem in one extra thing I want to do.

I want to update text view when I type data in edittext((I know this part)).

the problem: is that if I have a button and when I click that button I want to post the text entered and end the updating method.

this is the code:

```
//in a class
//I declared these objects and found them by id
Button button;
TextView textview;
EditText edittext;


//in the oncreate method

//I made a string variable called enteredData;

String enteredData=edittext.getText().toString();

//now to update the textview each time I type data in edittext

edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            textview.setText(enteredData);


            }
        }
    });


    //The problem here

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @override
    public void onClick(View view){
    //how to set the text finally into the text view and stop the update of
     //this text view

    }
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: post the text entered and end the updating method. ?? what do you mean by this post where to post

Comment: @eLemEnt the problem is that when I click the button to set the final text in the textview, the textview still goes into updating, its not stable anymore even on button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple try this-

```
String enteredData=edittext.getText().toString();
Boolean pauseTextEntered=false;

edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(!pauseTextEntered)
            textview.setText(enteredData);


            }
        }
    });


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @override
    public void onClick(View view){
    if(!pauseTextEntered)
    textview.setText(enteredData);
    pauseTextEntered=true;    
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@override
public void onClick(View view){
String enteredData=edittext.getText().toString();
textview.setText(enteredData);
textview.setEnabled(false);   // you have to enable again 
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Hasan BT

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView textView;
Button button;
EditText editText;
boolean flag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblHeader);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFragmentOne);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);


    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!flag)
                textView.setText(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    flag = true;
}

}
```

Comment: @HasanB.T try new answer.. I know it will work and then tell me what exactly you want on button click

Comment: I want exactly on button click to stop the updating of the textview everytime I type data in edittext.

Comment: @HasanB.T that means once button is clicked you want to stop updating textview ?? untill unless user to dont click on button textview should get updated as edit text gets changed

Comment: textview will get updated as you type text inside edittext until you dont click on button. Once you click on button textview will stop updating. Hasan BT also do you want user to stop entering data inside your edittext ??